# Difference /etc/init.d/apache2 and apache2ctl

Tags: php, apache, exec, restart, sudoers

I want remote restart Apache in Php function exec

So i add nobody in

```
/etc/sudoers
```

but `exec('sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart')` is not working.

just catch shutdown signal, shutdown and not start.

and i try exec('sudo apache2ctl restart') and this is working.

but i don't know why these have difference.

who know that situation please tell me about it.

for reference this environment is Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: Because `/etc/init.d/apache2` in a script, I'm pretty sure it's not gonna virtually append another `sudo` command to the binaries it actually runs. Hence the need to tap into the final command, and not a script run this command without another further sudoing.

Comment: I don't understand. Would you tell me easily about that? please.